# Markdown: Footnotes with Bullet Points

Tags: markdown, footnotes

I know that markdown has mixed support for footnotes. The flavour that I am using does support them, but I have the following question:

Can Markdown footnotes include additional paragraphs or bulleted lists?

It doesn’t seem to work on the Markdown edit I’m using (MacDown), but maybe I have missed something, or maybe some other flavours do support more sophisticated footnotes?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You say that the flavour you're using supports footnotes, but you don't specify which flavour that is. I'm going to assume [MultiMarkdown](https://github.com/fletcher/MultiMarkdown/) since it was one of the first to add [footnotes](https://github.com/fletcher/MultiMarkdown/wiki/MultiMarkdown-Syntax-Guide#footnotes).

You can generally tell Markdown to "continue" things by indenting further blocks by four spaces or one tab.

In MultiMarkdown this seems to work for footnotes:

```
Test paragraph[^footnote].

[^footnote]: Footnote text

    * One
    * Two

    More text.

        Code block.
```

Comment: Yes, this method of nesting items in a footnote is common across many implementations.